# Having trouble adding a column to mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a database that doesnt have a primary key or unique id. Im trying to add an ID column that will hold a primary key but getting an error that the table exists

> ALTER TABLE `table 1` ADD `uid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

but am getting this error

> ## 1050 - Table 'test/#sql-ib30' already exists

any advice? Im trying to do it using phpmyadmin

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table 1...` What is this `1` for ?

Comment: the name of the table is just table 1

Comment: Don't use table names with spaces in them. Use underscores instead.

Comment: Yes. You should name it `table_1`, because the way you do it I think mysql will try to tind 2 tables, one called `table` and another one called `1`

Comment: Just tried that and it said that table doesnt exist

Comment: found this searching around in relation to the reference of the #sql-ib30 but I dont know what error happened to recreate it      http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/229560

Comment: the fastest wasy to fix this was for me to create a new database and reupload the data, then adding the unique identifier column as the primary key succeeded